# Problem with deleting emails using poplib

Tags: python, poplib

I have written a program to read outlook emails using poplib and outputting only the filtered data into json and then deleting all the emails. But with the code I wrote It's not deleting all the emails and deleting only one email. Can anybody help me.

code:

```
def read_mail_from_pop3_server():
    try:
        conn = poplib.POP3_SSL(EMAIL_SERVER, 995)
        print('Logging into Office365')
        conn.user(EMAIL_USER)
        conn.pass_(EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        mail_count = len(conn.list()[1])
        print("You have %d email messages." % mail_count)
        output = []
        for i in range(mail_count):
            raw_email = b"\n".join(conn.retr(i + 1)[1])
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
            items_list = msg.items()
            dict_items = OrderedDict(items_list)
            email_body = ''
            if msg.is_multipart():
                ...
            else:
                ...
            dict_items.update({'Body': email_body})
            dict_obj = TatvamObjDict.load_fromFile('MailJsonData.Json')

            dict_obj.review.original_text = dict_items['Body'].lstrip() if 'Body' in dict_items else "".strip()
            ...

            if "<xyz@gmail.com>" in dict_items.itervalues():
                output.append(dict_obj)

            with open('del_check.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(output, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
                f.write('\n')

       # # deleting emails directly by email index(count)
       conn.dele(mail_count)
       conn.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just flag one message, with index `mail_count` for deletion (upon quit, by what the poplib docs says). You should indent that line to put it inside the `for` loop and then give it the proper message index.